# Which version of MS Teams did we start getting green color success message?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am seeing a green color success message appearing on submit action. It is no problem for me, but I wanted to know which version of MS Teams did the success message start to appear.

I found a [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blogs/five-new-features-enhancing-adaptive-cards-in-microsoft-teams/) on the developer Microsoft website, but there is no official word on the MS Teams version.

Also found a [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/487391/the-green-color-success-message-appears-for-some-o.html) on the Microsoft community, but there is confirmation on version

Any input about the version is appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug and the new feature of the adaptive card,  You can go through the following Microsoft blog for more information about this feature.

**Reference:**

[Five new features enhancing Adaptive Cards in Microsoft Teams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blogs/five-new-features-enhancing-adaptive-cards-in-microsoft-teams/)

Comment: Rajeesh, I am aware this is not a bug and a new feature for the adaptive cards. I have gone through this doc already. What I wanted to know is, starting which version of MS Teams do we start seeing this message? Because in my org, few of us are seeing this success message and others are not.

Comment: As per my understanding, 1.2 is the supported version of ms teams but if you are using 1.3 or 1.4 then there will be a chance because these versions are fully supported for webchat.

Comment: This feature is terrible. It disturbs the user experience of many bots in teams, cause the green "success" bar assumes for the user, that the action was successful. In reality it is only showing that a button was clicked and has no relation to the real action that happened. I hope the bot-framework developers are aware of that and will remove that feature soon again.